# How to force page number to appear on titlepage

Tags: titles, page-numbering

I want the title page to display the page number 1 and every page after that to have a page number with no breaks. What do I need to change?

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Abstract}
test
\end{document}
```

title.tex:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\textsc{\LARGE University of Beer}\\[1.5cm]

This thesis is Submitted to UoB\\[0.5cm]
For the degree of Doctor of Philosophy\\[0.5cm]

% Title
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Finance \\[0.4cm] }

\HRule \\[1.5cm]


\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
John \textsc{Smith}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Prof.~John \textsc{Smith Snr}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\vfill
% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: So, even for the first page of a chapter? If so, add `\makeatletter \let\ps@empty\ps@plain \makeatother` to your preamble.

Comment: What do you mean by *page number with no breaks*? Continuing page numbers without intermediate reset?

Comment: Is that minipage really necessary?

Comment: @Christian I copied it from the web if it can be simplified I would be happy to do it

Comment: @Werner that get displays page 1 on the title page but the next page (which is the page with the table of contents) also is numbered 1? I want the title page to be number 1, then contents page to be number 2 and so on.

Comment: @Bazman: Werner's suggestion should work, but I believe that `titlepage` internally uses a `\pagenumbering` command, which resets the page number!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an automatic `\stepcounter{page}` explicitly at the end of the `titlepage` environment using the `\xpatchcmd` from egreg's `xpatch` package. In conjunction with the suggestion by Werner about the `\ps@empty` command, this should provide the desired feature.

Since `titlepage` is an environment, there is an automatic `\endtitlepage` command/hook, which is called at the end of the command, so it's sufficient to append the `\stepcounter` command to `\endtitlepage`

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xapptocmd{\endtitlepage}{\clearpage\stepcounter{page}}{}{}%


% Taken from Werner's comment
\makeatletter 
\let\ps@empty\ps@plain%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}
%\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Abstract}
test
\end{document}
```

The `title.tex` file is untouched and should be used from the OP above.