# First Page number is not showing in exam environment

Tags: page-numbering, exam

In my document the first page number "Page 1" is not showing at bottom, but the other pages are alright. How can it be shown? I'm using `\documentclass[12pt]{exam}` environment.

Here's an MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15] % 15 paragraphs (almost 2 pages) of filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean the document class `exam`... And most likely it is a titlepage not having a page number

Comment: yeah ... so is there any way that I can add the first page number in 'exam' environment?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202251/how-to-force-page-number-to-appear-on-titlepage?s=2|1.2435

Comment: The magic word is: Minimal working example ;-) Please provide this!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I thought you were going to write "The magic word is PLEASE". :-)

Comment: @Mico: I wrote: Please provide this! That's nice enough ;-)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of providing an MWE (minimum working example). I've also added the tag "exam".

Comment: @Mico: Thou shalt not do what is the O.P.'s work ;-)

Comment: Try `\footer{}{Page \thepage}{}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}% <-----
\lipsum[1-15] % 15 paragraphs (almost 2 pages) of filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\footer{}{Page \thepage}{}`

Comment: @egreg Can you give a reason?

Comment: The class documentation is quite clear about that: section 11.3.1. One *can* use `\cfoot`, but I wouldn't.

Comment: @egreg Looking at the documentation, i don't see a problem in using either. Both are mentioned.